# Weird edges with solidify and subsurf modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am making a model of a ferrari 458 and and currently I'm facing a problem I can't solve. When using the solidify and subsurf modifiers, the areas where the mesh is connected on the diffuser have creases. I have tried rebuilding all the area from the beginning, smoothing the vertices, faces and edges and merging by distance, but nothing worked as intended.

Any thoughts on this?

[image: Subsurf on edit mode]

[image: Subsurf on object mode]

[image: No subsurf and object mode]

Comment: Have you tried swapping the subsurf and solidify modifiers in the modifier stack? I can't test it right now but I would expect there could be issues if the solidify modifier comes before the subsurf one.

Comment: I just tried it out and it didn't work. All detail in the area was destroyed after changing modifier priority. Thank you for your advice though.

Comment: please share this part of your file, here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ok, i uploaded it

Comment: @ Johnny you need to share the link  ;)

Comment: @moonboots I tried your solution and it is working i believe. Thank for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inner faces, what we see is the shading between the outer and inner faces. If I select these faces and hide them:

[image]

I can see this face:

[image]

Delete these faces.